# algorithm: find count of numbers within a given range

Tags: c++, algorithm

given an unsorted number array where there can be duplicates, pre-process the array so that to find the count of numbers within a given range, the time is O(1).

For example, `7,2,3,2,4,1,4,6`. The count of numbers both `>= 2` and `<= 5` is `5`. `(2,2,3,4,4)`.

Comment: is the "pre-processing" part O(1)? I don't see how that would be possible. I am guessing you mean to pre-process the array such that the result can count numbers of given criteria in O(1)?

Comment: Sounds like homework? If it is, please tag it so.

Comment: What is the possible min/max ranges allowed?

Answer (score 5):

Sort the array. For each element in the sorted array, insert that element into a hash table, with the value of the element as the key, and its position in the array as the associated value. Any values that are skipped, you'll need to insert as well.

To find the number of items in a range, look up the position of the value at each end of the range in the hash table, and subtract the lower from the upper to find the size of the range.

Comment: I'd only do this if the input array is never sparse, otherwise you might construct a very large hash map. Alternatively store the individual count of each element in the hash map and check for every item in the range. Wouldn't be O(1) though.

Comment: how would that solution deal with duplicate numbers in the original array?  For the OP's example, how would you distinguish the first 4 from the second one?

Comment: @pmr: yes, if your input was extremely sparse, this would be pretty wasteful. @DShook: You'd have a couple of choices.  Two obvious ones would be to track both the first and last positions, and to track the first position and count of equal elements.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think Jerry and I proposed basically the same strategy, if not quite the same tools. Duplicate numbers shouldn't be a problem under his scheme if rather than subtracting hash[lower] from hash[upper], you just subtract hash[lower-1] from hash[upper], assuming that you consistently listed the position of the value in the sorted array at the rightmost position.

Comment: You could probably save some space by bucketing. So if input range is [l,u] you look for the closest multiple of 10 near l and u and use that for the hash lookup. And then do another hash lookup of no more than 20 items which were extra/missed.

Comment: There is no reason to use a hash table as you are inserting a key-value pair for every key in the range [MIN, MAX]. Just use an array.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds suspiciously like one of those clever interview questions some interviewers like to ask, which is usually associated with hints along the way to see how you think.

Regardless... one possible way of implementing this is to make a list of the counts of numbers equal to or less than the list index.

For example, from your list above, generate the list: 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8. Then you can count the numbers between 2 and 5 by subtracting list[1] from list[5].

Comment: Even then, it's O(1) only if the numbers themselves comes from a limited range (e.g, if they are guaranteed to fit in a regular int).

Comment: To be pedantic, it doesn't cease to be O(1) if your list type doesn't fit in a regular int... it ceases to work entirely (as the memory required exceeds addressable space on many/most systems). This system can handle value counts that are any amount larger than an int, however. As there's no reason the generated count array can't use something more complex than a uint as a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to access in O(1), the data structure needed would be memory-intensive.
With Hash Table, in worst case access would take O(n)

My Solution:
Build a 2D matrix.
array = {2,3,2,4,1,4,6} Range of numbers = 0 to 6 so n = 7
So we've to create nxn matrix.
array[i][i] represents total count of element = i
so array[4][4] = 2  (since 4 appears 2 times in array)
array[5][5] = 0
array[5][2] = count of numbers both >= 2 and <= 5 = 5

```
//preprocessing stage 1: Would populate a[i][i] with total count of element = i
a[n][n]={0};
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
  a[i][i]++;
}

//stage 2
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<i;j++)
     a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][i];
//we are just adding count of element=i to each value in i-1th row and we get ith row.
```

Now (5,2) would query for a[5][2] and would give answer in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{   
    int arr[8]={7,2,3,2,4,1,4,6};
    int count[9];
    int total=0;    

    memset(count,0, sizeof(count));

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        count[arr[i]]++;

    for(int k=0;k<9;k++)
    {
        if(k>=2 && k<=5 && count[k]>0 )
        {
            total= total+count[k] ;     
        }
    }

    printf("%d:",total);
    return 0;
}
```