# Finding number of integers within a range

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am reading introduction to algorithms 3rd edition and i ran into the following: Suppose that we are given n integers in the range 0 to k and we want to find out how many of these integers are in the range [a,b] for given integers a and b. It has the brute solution, but then it says that by a preprocessing phase on the input, this query can be completed in Θ(1) time, and this proprocessing phase takes O(n+k) time. I am thinking about sorting the integers, but sorting at least takes O(nlogn) time, which exceeds O(n+k). What can be done for the preprocessing phase? Thanks

Comment: Use [Hash Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586200/algorithm-find-count-of-numbers-within-a-given-range). It will be O(1).

Comment: which author of the algorithms book? when citing a book, state the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the numbers are in range [0,k] you can use counting sort to sort them in O(n+k) time.

Once you have the counts, you can take the prefix sums of that count array, which will tell you the number of numbers in the range [0, a]. O(k) time.

Using that you can answer queries for [a,b] by taking the appropriate difference, in O(1) time.

Comment: Thanks, but  did not understand what you mean by "we can use counting to sort them"

Comment: @bigO: Count how many zeroes are there, how many ones are there etc. You maintain a counts[0...k] array (initialized to 0). Now each time you get the number j, you increment counts[j].

Comment: looks to be the desired solution

Comment: @harold: I only mentioned sorting because bigO was thinking in those terms. I thought he might be familar with counting sort and would immediately get the answer...

Comment: @AlexWien: Counting sort is a common term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: ok thanks, but i was not sure, if really the full counting sort is aplied here, or if only the first part of the countng sort: the histogramm is created.

Comment: @AlexWien: Sorry for not responding earlier. I only mentioned it because OP was thinking of sorting(see question).